# Detecting trauma with EEG?

Tags: eeg, anxiety, trauma

My parent went to a Psychologist because of anxiety and panic attacks. Nicely i knew that she uses EEG for diagnostics. So he went to see her, but he told me that during the EEG she asked him for 2 task:

1 Count backward from 100 to zero.

2 Listen a list of words (eg. college, father, mother, etc.). According to the psychologist in this way we'll locate if one of this word is related to a psychological trauma due to some EEG variation during the listening.

I've looking for some references about those. I understand that the first task is some related to attention and memory-recall functions but i didn't found anything about the second task.

Any idea?

Comment: Where did you find out about the purpose of the first task? Could you include this reference/link?

Comment: I found it here https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/10768/why-would-i-be-asked-to-count-backwards-by-3-from-100-in-a-psychological-test and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_sevens

Comment: Thank you! You can edit this into your answer; don't just paste it at the end, but incorporate it as if you would have included it the first time around. Comments on Stack Exchange sites are temporary.